# How you can create one-to-one relationship from different assembly in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want using simple table splitting in my project for learning about that but how you can make that in different assembly?
I have two class library that named as `MyApp.Core` and `MyApp.CommerceService` 
In `.Core` project I have `User` entity:

```
  public partial class User
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; } 

        public Customer Customer { get; set; } 
    }
```

In `.CommerceService` I have `Customer` entity:

```
  public partial class Customer
    {
        private ICollection<Address> _addresses;

        public Customer()
        {
            this.CustomerGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public long UserId { get; set; } 

        public User User { get; set; } 

        public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }

        public int VendorId { get; set; }

        public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
        {
            get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new List<Address>()); }
            protected set { _addresses = value; }
        }
    }
```

That's fine if `Customer` entity placed in `.Core` project. Now I have problem with adding assembly references because that makes cycle. 
I'm student please give me a tip for this. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing in common with EF Core. Simply you can't have 2 assemblies referencing each other. What's the point of using separate assemblies if they need to reference objects from each other?

Comment: @IvanStoev Nothing just want learning more. How you can solve this?

Comment: I won't. Rather than trying to solve unresolvable, I would remove the origin of the problem, i.e. won't use separate assemblies for interrelated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with a circular dependency of your projects the simplest way to get around this is to extract all of your entities to another project I would create a new project MyApp.Entities or MyApp.DataAccess.

Place all of your entities in this project and you can then reference this project from both core and CommerceService.  I would also suggest moving any EF related files such as context here as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my tutorial project plan that makes ugly code. Because I'm using ABP framework and many entities comes from that framework. I want make a simple modular app. So a module should have own entities.

Comment: @CS-Beginner in what way is this ugly?  if you have entities from a framework you can leave them were ever they are meant to sit and still separate out any of your own.

Comment: User entity comes from framework so I need placing my Customer entity in User assembly. Then I need placing all commerce entities too where the entity have relation with customer. That makes ugly code

Comment: @CS-Beginner if you have a circular dependency this is simply just bad code.  you need to separate your entities into different projects to allow them to be referenced or you need to move your logic into another project that can reference  both your core and commerce projects.  google Multilayered architecture theirs a fantastic article on Wikipedia.